# Custom View not inflating

Tags: android, custom-controls, custom-component

I am trying to create my custom view through xml, but the screen does not show my view, s it is not inflating. My custom view xml is as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/profileSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAdvertise"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_minus" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAdvertise"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="asdas" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

I have my custom `View` class as:

```
public class MyCustomView extends View{

    TextView textAdvertise;
    ImageView imageAdvertise;
    View view;
    ViewSwitcher switcher ;

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (layoutInflater != null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

        }

        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        textAdvertise = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAdvertise);
        imageAdvertise = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAdvertise);
        switcher = (ViewSwitcher) view.findViewById(R.id.profileSwitcher);
        startAnimation();

    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                for (;;) {
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        hRefresh.sendEmptyMessage(5);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    Handler hRefresh = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 5:
                switcher.showNext();
                // To go back to the first view, use switcher.showPrevious()
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

and in my base xml layout where I have to show the `View`, is one button and and my `View` as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<com.example.viewswitcher.MyCustomView 
    android:id="@+id/MyView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    />
```

Can anyone please tell me what it is going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will see nothing because `MyCustomView` doesn't have any content as you wrote it. First of all I would use one of the `ViewGroups` children instead of `View`(like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc):

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {

    TextView textAdvertise;
    ImageView imageAdvertise;
    View view;
    ViewSwitcher switcher ;

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (layoutInflater != null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, this, true);
        }
        initialize();
    }

     public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int theme) {
         super(context, attrs, theme);
     }
// ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for help.. It worked.. Actually in my my layout inflator i have written   view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null); this null causes problem.. instead i put "this" It worked .. thanks buddy !!

Comment: what edit you have made in question... and one more thing it worked because i have extended LinearLayout instead of view.. why this so?? Any link or post regarding this detail.. thanks

Comment: @Rashmi I've edited your question to better format the question's code. The `View` class represents a single `View` object, it doesn't accept children `View`s like you're trying to add to it with the `inflate` method(in fact if you look at the `inflate` method docs you'll see that the second parameter is a `ViewGroup`). Instead a `ViewGroup`(`LinearLayout` is a subclass of `ViewGroup`) represents a `View`(in fact it's a subclass of the super class `View`) that accepts children `Views`. I don't know any links but you could look at the docs for `View` and `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Solution does not work. You have to use this call: `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.color_chooser, this)`, as `NullPointerException` mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to inflate your layout.
**Edit**

```
  View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_name, null);
```

This will return the parent layout of your xml file then you can directly use it or you can find any other view by using

**Edit**

```
headerView.findViewById(R.id.view_id);
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is not a custom View. Maybe you should inherit from Fragment class insted of View.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) for how implementing a own Fragment.

Comment: Sorry fragments are not useful in my case.. because i have to give compatibility to my app from android 2.1

Comment: You can use Android Support Package. [link] (http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). The minimum versión is 4 (1.6, i think).